# iOS Custom UILabel background color seems translucent

Tags: ios, colors, background, label

I have a subclass of UILabel with IBInspectable UIColor. I set its background color with this one but the color is different on the screen once my app is started. The color seems translucent like a translucent navigation bar.

The alpha component is 1.

I would like to have the initial color without translucent.

Have you a solution ?

Comment: There is no code for that

Answer (score 0):

`UIView` itself has an `alpha` property, which affects the view itself, but also all subviews:

[image]

So one of the following is true:

- your `UILabel`s `alpha` value is < 1
- one of your `UILabel`s parent views `alpha` value is < 1
- your `UILabel` `backgroundColor`s `alpha` value is < 1

Comment: I used the Debug View Hierarchy and I don't think it's about alpha because a normal view with my color is equal to R:0,07 G:0,24 B:0,36 A:1 and my label is equal to R:0,07 G:0,3 B:0,44 A:1 although I set the same UIColor.

Comment: As written, you have to differenciate in between the colors alpha value, the views alpha value and its parent views alpha value. I ran in to this issue a lot until I got it. For more help, post code.